# installing bigquery command line on fedora release 8

Tags: python, fedora, zlib, google-bigquery

I am following installing instructions from [installation steps](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool#installation)

I am ending up with the following error

```
#python setup.py install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/mnt/ravi/BQTools/bigquery-2.0.6/ez_setup.py", line 76, in use_setuptools
    return do_download()       
  File "/mnt/ravi/BQTools/bigquery-2.0.6/ez_setup.py", line 72, in do_download
    import setuptools; setuptools.bootstrap_install_from = egg
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I assumed I had to install zlib to get rid of this error, but it doesn't help

```
#yum install zlib

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * updates-newkey: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * fedora: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * updates: kdeforge.unl.edu
updates-newkey                                          | 2.3 kB     00:00     
fedora                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                 | 2.6 kB     00:00     
s3tools                                                 | 1.7 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Package zlib-1.2.3-14.fc8.i386 already installed and latest version

Nothing to do
```

a search gives the following result

```
#yum search zlib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * updates-newkey: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * fedora: kdeforge.unl.edu
 * updates: kdeforge.unl.edu 
================================ Matched: zlib ================================
arm-gp2x-linux-zlib.noarch : Cross Compiled zlib Library targeted at arm-gp2x-
                           : linux
iptstate.i386 : A top-like display of IP Tables state table entries
jzlib.i386 : JZlib re-implementation of zlib in pure Java
jzlib-demo.i386 : Examples for jzlib
jzlib-javadoc.i386 : Javadoc for jzlib
minizip.i386 : Minizip manipulates files from a .zip archive
minizip-devel.i386 : Development files for the minizip library
ocaml-cryptokit.i386 : OCaml library of cryptographic and hash functions
perl-Archive-Tar.noarch : A module for Perl manipulation of .tar files
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.i386 : Low-Level Interface to the zlib compression
                            : library
perl-Compress-Zlib.noarch : A module providing Perl interfaces to the zlib
                          : compression library
perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.noarch : Perl interface to allow reading and writing of
                             : gzip and zip data
perl-IO-Zlib.noarch : Perl IO:: style interface to Compress::Zlib
perl-POE-Filter-Zlib.noarch : POE filter wrapped around Compress::Zlib
php-pecl-phar.i386 : Allows running of complete applications out of .phar files
rb_libtorrent-devel.i386 : Development files for rb_libtorrent
zlib.i386 : The zlib compression and decompression library
zlib-devel.i386 : Header files and libraries for Zlib development
zziplib.i386 : Lightweight library to easily extract data from zip files
zziplib-devel.i386 : Development files for the zziplib library
zziplib-utils.i386 : Utilities for the zziplib library
```

I am not sure if zlib is installed correctly

```
# zlib
-bash: zlib: command not found
```

Please suggest next steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the copy of python on your machine was built without zlib support. Luckily, the only reason zlib is needed is to install setuptools, and there's an easier way to do that in your case -- just try:

```
yum install python-setuptools
```

and then you can either proceed as you were, or (even easier) just type `easy_install -U bigquery` to install bq.

Comment: I guess I had tried that but did not work so later on switched to an Ubuntu machine and things went smooth ahead